# Worker finished without being first started

Tags: java, android, gradle

i build a android project in AndroidStudio, use command 'gradle build' or directly 'run'.
then the problem appear.
the log is below:

```
> Task :tools:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :tools:bundleLibResDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :vrclient:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :vrui:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :vrui:checkDebugDuplicateClasses FAILED
> Task :navisdk:bundleLibResDebug
> Task :vrclient:generateDebugRFile
> Task :vrclient:javaPreCompileDebug
> Task :client_user:bundleLibResDebug
> Task :emall_client:bundleLibResDebug

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':vrui:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> 1 exception was raised by workers:
  java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Worker finished without being first started
```

help me, please

Comment: Post your gradle build file here. There might be possibility of duplication in third party libraries.

Comment: i cleaned the project, then "build", it works. interesting

Comment: Has anyone figured a better solution than doing a clean build? We are getting this error maybe 50% of the time, and clean does not improve that 50% rate.